# Sqoop Incremental Import lastmodified: Howto merge Avro?

Tags: sqoop, avro

After running two incremental imports of the same table `import_old` and `import_new` using `--as--avrofile` I simply don't know and I am not able to `merge` the two.

I see the following Exception:

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""fields":[{"name":"cluster_id""`

Is there some Avro `--jar-file` or `--class-name` I can use?

It must by very simple, but I don't get the trick. I use the following sqoop version:

Sqoop 1.4.3  / git commit id 82fde21d0f6c89059bade4588f3ba6989989dc76 / 
Compiled by hari on Tue Feb 26 11:28:37 PST 2013`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop currently do not support merge of avro files (which is required by the incremental import in lastmodified mode). There is already JIRA [SQOOP-1094](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1094) to add such support.

Comment: The Jira ticket seems to be solved by now. Any ideea if the avro append works?